# Update error on stored procedure on updating time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that update the actual date of an answer but return a conversion error :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MensajeCompletado] 
    @id int,
    @RESPUESTA nvarchar(50),
    @resp int = 1 output
AS
    if Exists(select * from OFICIOS where IdOficio = @id)
    begin
        update OFICIOS 
        set Respuesta = @RESPUESTA, 
            FechaRecibido = CONVERT(nvarchar(11), GETDATE(), 105), 
            Estatus = 2
        where IdOficio = @id

        set @resp = 0
    end
    else
    begin
        set  @resp = 1
    end
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: what data type is FechaRecibido ?

Comment: FechaRecibido is date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `FechaRecibido` is a `DATE` - ***why on earth*** are you converting `GETDATE()` into a `NVARCHAR` then!?

Just assign the output of `GETDATE` (or better: `SYSDATETIME`) to your column by casting to a `DATE`:

```
update OFICIOS 
set Respuesta = @RESPUESTA, 
    FechaRecibido = CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE),
    Estatus = 2
where IdOficio = @id
```

but **most definitely** don't convert to a `nvarchar` !!

Answer (score 1):

It is failing because you are returning a string format that it cannot implicitly convert. Just `CAST` it to `DATE` instead.  This should work:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MensajeCompletado] 
    @id int,
    @RESPUESTA nvarchar(50),
    @resp int = 1 output
AS
    if Exists(select * from OFICIOS where IdOficio = @id)
    begin
        update OFICIOS 
        set Respuesta = @RESPUESTA, 
            FechaRecibido = Cast (GETDATE() as Date)
            Estatus = 2
        where IdOficio = @id

        set @resp = 0
    end
    else
    begin
        set  @resp = 1
    end
```